# Debugging C# application with dll's

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have sources of main executable and several dll's written on C#. If there any way to debug them together in VS, so that when the main programm calls some method from dll, debugger goes there too?

Comment: As long as you have symbols, that will just work.

Comment: You need symbol file (PDB) to match the source files to the binaries.

Comment: @SLaks Always? I can't remember why by I've had to manually load the PDB's from the Modules window.

Comment: @ConradFrix Well if they're not along with the DLLs or in one of paths VS is watching then yes, they need to be loaded manually.

Comment: @BartoszKP It was probably something like that or some other goofy nonsense I was doing. In any case the OP should be using the module window or looking at the output window to find out what modules are loaded and the state of the of the symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DLLs are written in .Net, then your Visual Studio IDE Debugger will naturally follow them as long as you have the PDBs.

However, if the DLLs are written in non .Net, such as native "C/C++" code, then you will need to set your IDE debugger to mixed mode using both the appropriate .Net setting and native. By default, the IDE debugger will be set to "automatic" and may or may not decide to include native in your debugging options. Just set it manually if the automatic doesn't include "native" when you are trying to include the non-.Net DLLs.